# Batch 'else' (or any commands of these kind) not working with a password set at random

Tags: batch-file

**My code**:

```
::Correct

@echo off

echo Password, please!

::Wrong
set p = %random%
set /p = 
if /p == %p% goto true
else goto false

        ::Correct
            :true
            echo Correct!
            pause
            exit
                       :false
                       echo Wrong! Too bad! Bye!
                       pause
                       exit
```

I pointed out the section that's wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. The batch file should ask you for a password (that's set at random) and if you guess right say "Correct!", if you guess wrong it should say "Wrong! Too bad! Bye!". Right now, whatever I do it just says that there's no 'else' command. Please help in a way that works (not the else if that doesn't work).

Comment: Remove the word `else`. You don't need it.

Comment: `if /?`, `set /?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of errors.

```
set p = %random%
```

Sets a variable named **p<kbd>Space</kbd>** to ***<kbd>Space</kbd>randomnumber***

Spaces are sigificant on **both** sides of the `=` in a `set` command

```
set /p =
```

The syntax for a `set /p` command is `set /p varname="prompt string " Note that the spacing is still significant, and your code fails to specify what variable to load.

```
if /p == %p% goto true
```

Since `/p` is a string constant, then the variable `p`'s contents must be the same as this constant (ie `/p`) for this to be true. `/p` is not a variable - if it was, you'd need to access it using `%/p%` - and since you were setting **p<kbd>Space</kbd>** instead of `p`, the `%p%` will be *empty* so the command would be interpreted as

```
if /p == goto true
```

Now, since `/p` and `goto` are not identical strings, the command `true` is not executed, so you get no error report.

```
else goto false
```

an orphaned `else`. The syntax for the `else` clause of a `if` is

```
if condition (
 dothis_if_true
) else (
 dothis_if_false
)
```

The positioning of the parentheses is critical. The first open must be on the same physical line as the `if` (or **do**) and if an else is used then both the preceding `)` and succeeding `(` must occur on the same physical line as the `else` **and** there must be a space between the `else` keyword and the parentheses.

---

```
:Correct

@echo off
echo Password, please!

:Wrong
set /a p=%random%
set "pass="
set /p "pass=Your password "
if not defined pass goto wrong

if "%pass%"=="%p%" (
 goto true
) else (
 goto false
)

:true
echo Correct!
pause
exit

:false
echo Wrong! Too bad! Bye!
pause
exit
```

Note: initial `::` on a line is often used as a comment as it's easier to type and less intrusive than `rem`. This trick does not work properly within a 'block statement' (a parenthesised series of statements) because it is actually a broken label.

I've changed the `::` comments to simple labels as I needed to use a label for the revised code.

```
set /a p=random
```

This sets `p` to a string given by the `/a` arithmetic result of the formula in the argument. This is simply `%random%`, a random number 0..32767.

```
set "pass="
```

This simply sets the variable `pass` to *nothing*. The quotes are inserted to tell `cmd` that any spaces appearing after the closing `"` are **not** to be included in the value assigned.

```
set /p "pass=Your password "
```

accepts input from the keyboard to the variable `pass`. Note that if the response from the keyboard is simply <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the variable will remain unchanged, it will not acquire a value of *nothing*; hence the reason it was initialised to *nothing*

```
if not defined pass goto wrong
```

If you didn't type anything, keep going around the loop until a response is received.

```
if "%pass%"=="%p%" (
 goto true
) else (
 goto false
)
```

if the string input from the keyboard is the same as the string version of the random number chosen, go to `true`...

Note that since the string accepted from the keyboard is uncontrolled - it might contain separators like spaces - then the entire string is enclosed in quotes to group the string together as one element. This has to be *exactly* matched by the other side, so we need to quote that item too. This isn't bullet-proof, but it's less vulnerable than to omit the quotes.

You might want to try adjusting the prompt to

```
set /p "pass=Your [%p%] password "
```

for testing purposes. This will show the password in the prompt, so you should then have a better chance of guessing than 1 in 32,768.

Comment: Thanks! That was a bunch of useful information! Would you please write the corrected code? I **am** not used to the "programming" english, after all.

Comment: Edit: **Thanks again**! It's really clear now! I'll keep upgrading it. (i.e. backdoor, menu, a basic game and exit)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and see the differences.

```
@echo off
set "p=%random%"
set /p "g=Password please! "
If "%g%"=="%p%" (goto :true) else (goto :false)
:true
echo Correct!
pause
exit
:false
echo Wrong! Too bad! Bye!
pause
exit
```

Comment: I still do not understand. Granted, it works, but I do not undestand the code if it's wrote like that and neither do I understand some of the "rules" applied here.

Comment: The full explanation of what my code does was answered by Magoo after I wrote it. Please take a look at that then come back with further questions as necessary. I did not add anything new to your script, just fixed what you had.

Comment: He wrote 
`if condition (
 dothis_if_true
) else (
 dothis_if_false
)`
not 
`If "%g%"=="%p%" (goto :true) else (goto :false)`
Is there no difference?

Comment: So messy. Much misunderstanding.
You should pu the **`** there to differentiate the code from the rest.

Comment: My answer is clear, Magoo's answer is clear, my comment **there is no difference** is clear. I will however rewrite it the comment for you. There's no difference. **if** _[ condition -_ **"%g%"=="%p%** _] [ dothis_if_true -_ **(goto :true)** _]_ **else** _[ dothis_if_false -_ **(goto :false)** _]._

Comment: Seriously? I did understand "there is no difference" I just didn't understand the part from "if", as I said you should really put it in the " **`** ".

Comment: I have explained it the best I can in an inline comment. (I've shown you what the condition equates to, what the dothis_if_true equates to and what the dothis_if_false equates to). If you have a specific question regarding your lack of understanding please ask it and I will do my best to answer it, but asking me to format my inline comments to suit your perceived understanding seems fruitless.